# Trying to change image with jquery width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm having some issue with jquery. Im trying to change the src of the img tag using jquery and it workes fine when the width is decreasing but not increasing so if my width is 1920px from start and i shrink it to 600px it changes the image as it should but if i do the reversed of what i just said it wont change it's stuck on the 600px image.

```
var WinSize = function(){
 var w=$(window).width();
 if(w => 1920){
  $("#backImg").attr('src', 'assets/img/Code1920.PNG');
 }
 if(w => 1000){
  $("#backImg").attr('src', 'assets/img/Code1080.PNG');
 }
 if(w > 620) {
  $("#backImg").attr('src', 'assets/img/CodeMobile.PNG');
 }
};
$(document).ready(WinSize); 
$(window).resize(WinSize);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/srcset

Comment: why not just use a picture tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture (I prefer this to `srcset` as you get the picture you want at the requested breakpoint, where as `srcset` depends on what what screen res was loaded first if you resize downwards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions are in incorrect order, so everything above 1920 will also fall in the 1000 and 620 ifs. You should probably invert the logic to something like:

```
if(w < 1000){
  $("#backImg").attr('src', 'assets/img/CodeMobile.PNG');
 } else if(w < 1920){
  $("#backImg").attr('src', 'assets/img/Code1080.PNG');
 } else {
  $("#backImg").attr('src', 'assets/img/Code1920.PNG');
 }
```

jQuery width also takes into account scrollbar for example. It's possible the "full screen" width is not 1920px.

Answer (score 0):

ALL THREE of your `if` conditions apply to a screen above 1920px width, so they will all be executed in the order they are in the code, which results in the smallest image being applied, since that's the last one which applies. Just reverse the order of the three conditions.

Comment: besides, srcset would be the better solution